# Autocad right click event handler

Tags: c#, .net, autocad, autodesk, autocad-plugin

I have written this code:

```
int count = 1;

while (true)
{

    pointOptions.Message = "\nEnter the end point of the line: ";
    pointOptions.UseBasePoint = true;
    pointOptions.BasePoint = drawnLine.EndPoint;
    pointResult = editor.GetPoint(pointOptions);

    if (pointResult.Status == PromptStatus.Cancel)
    {
        break;
    }

    if (count == 1)
    {
        drawnLine.AddVertexAt(count, pointResult.Value.Convert2d(new Plane()), 0, 0, 0);
        blockTableRecord.AppendEntity(drawnLine);
        transaction.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(drawnLine, true);
    }
    else
    {
        stretch(drawnLine, pointResult.Value, Point3d.Origin);
    }

    editor.Regen();

    count++;
}
```

The code works fine but to coplete the drawing i have to type ESC, I want to make a right click or space bar click to close my loop.Can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It Was in `PromptPointOptions` See code example below:

```
// Set promptOptions
var pointOptions = new PromptPointOptions("\nSelect Next Point: ");
pointOptions.SetMessageAndKeywords("\nSelect Next Point: or Exit [Y]","Yes");
pointOptions.AppendKeywordsToMessage = true;
pointOptions.AllowArbitraryInput = true;
pointOptions.UseBasePoint = true;
pointOptions.BasePoint = drawnLine.EndPoint;

// While user wants to draw the polyline
while (pointResult.Status != PromptStatus.Keyword)
{
// Get point
pointResult = Editor.GetPoint(pointOptions);

// stop creating polyline
if (pointResult.Status == PromptStatus.Cancel)
    break;

if (count == 1) {

    // Get base point and add to the modelspace
    drawnLine.AddVertexAt(count, pointResult.Value.Convert2d(new Plane()), 0, 0, 0);
    blockTableRecord.AppendEntity(drawnLine);
    transaction.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(drawnLine, true);
} else

    // Grow the polyline
    stretch(drawnLine, pointResult.Value, Point3d.Origin);

// Regen
editor.Regen();

count++;
}
```

what you were looking for was `PromptPointOptions.SetMessageAndKeywords` and by changing your loop eval you will come out when the user selects yes and you can set that up for a spacebar press.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: PromptPointOptions im using and pointOptions is the variable.

Comment: Thank you that was what i was looking for but can i do it with right click or spacebar not with Y?

Comment: play around with it, Try taking out the Y. That is the best way to learn. :) see what you can set the keywords to.